# I want to use customized algorithm to expedite planning process.Is it supported in optaplanner?

Tags: algorithm, customization, optaplanner

I want to use customized algorithm to expedite planning process.Is it supported in optaplanner?If so, does it require full compliance with optaplanner standards?

Recently, I was working on the optaplanner project and needed to use custom planning algorithm for planning, so I would like to know whether optaplanner supports custom algorithms.

Comment: What do you mean by "custom algorithm"? Custom algorithm for what? Also, what do you mean by "optaplanner standards"? Please be more specific in your question.

Comment: I saw in the optaplanner official documentation that algorithms such as simulated annealing are already available and can be applied as long as the algorithm is configured in XML. However, I want to use my own algorithms to plan the problem in optaplanner. So ,does optaplanner allow external algorithms to solve problems?

Answer (score 1):

Technically, you can implement anything you like if you use the [custom solver phase](https://www.optaplanner.org/docs/optaplanner/latest/optimization-algorithms/optimization-algorithms.html#customSolverPhase). That said, if you decide to not use the core of OptaPlanner, I doubt you need the rest of OptaPlanner as well.